# Dealing with multiple BOOL combinations

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, boolean, combinations, boolean-logic

Here is the scenario: In my app I'm syncing some data, whenever there is some error when syncing I flag this in a `BOOL`. When all syncing is complete I want to display sync feedback (errors) for the user.

If there is ie a calendar sync error **and** a contact sync error I first display a `UIAlertView` with information about the calendar sync error, when the user has tapped "OK" I then display a `UIAlertView` with information about the contact sync error. To be able to know when the user has tapped "OK" I use completion blocks. So my code looks something like this:

```
if (calendarSyncFailed && contactSyncFailed && facebookSyncFailed && contactSyncConflicts) {

    [self displayCalendarSyncAlertCompletionBlock:^{ 

        [self displayContactsSyncAlertCompletionBlock:^{

            [self displayFacebookSyncAlertCompletionBlock:^{

                [self displayContactSyncConflictsAlertCompletionBlock:^{

                }];
            }];
        }];
    }];

} else if (calendarSyncFailed && contactSyncFailed && facebookSyncFailed) {

    [self displayCalendarSyncAlertCompletionBlock:^{ 

        [self displayContactsSyncAlertCompletionBlock:^{

            [self displayFacebookSyncAlertCompletionBlock:^{

            }];
        }];
    }];

} else if (contactSyncFailed && facebookSyncFailed && contactSyncConflicts) {

    [self displayContactsSyncAlertCompletionBlock:^{

        [self displayFacebookSyncAlertCompletionBlock:^{

            [self displayContactSyncConflictsAlertCompletionBlock:^{

            }];
        }];
    }];

} else if (you get the idea…) {

}
```

As you can see there will be alot of different combinations for dealing with these 4 boolean values and I was wondering if there is a more smarter/elegant way of coding this?

Comment: Bugging user with countless alerts is not a pleasant experience. I would go for either making a single message with all problems sorted with the most important first, or will show only one alert with the most important error and spare the others.

Comment: While I appreciate your input, this question was not about UI. Unfortunately all errors are equally important for the user so I can't "spare" any. Anyhow this is a rare condition when there actually will be 4 errors at once.

Comment: Still believe you should go for a single error message solution. Anyway, you could just set a second set of Boolean values like contactSyncFailedErrorNeedToShow. On error you set not one but two of them and use the second to ease your logic and have only one code block taking care of all errors which were not shown.

Comment: Waiting for didDismissWithButtonIndex as suggested by vaderkvarn is a good solution. However I agree with the other comments, this is a terrible user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I do agree with demosten that it would be better to have only one message, this is how I would do this with less code:

1. Use a mutable array as a property where you store your alertviews.
2. In the method where you test your conditions, create an alert view for every failure that evaluates to true, and put them in your array in the desired order. (This is the key part as you are only doing 4 tests, instead of 2^4 - 1 tests).
3. Implement the `UIAlertViewDelegate` method `alertView: didDismissWithButtonIndex:` something like this:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSInteger nextIndex = [self.alertViews indexOfObject:alertView] + 1;
    if (nextIndex < [self.alertViews count]){
    UIAlertView *next = [self.alertViews objectAtIndex: nextIndex];
        [next show];
    }
}
```